# Magic-line nav causing some troubles #works only on hrefs included in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

Im using multiple (2) jquery versions on a site, i thought that it was a problem, but it doesnt seem so. I found out that i actually got a problem with magic-line navigation http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/ .

What happens is that it works only on sites that are included in the menu itself. Lets say im on projects site(that is included in the menu itself), everything works ok, but when i open a view of a certain project, the "underline" effect stops working, this is how it looks:

[image: a not workin magic line]

i didnt sleep for 4 days, im late for deadline , my brain hurts, plx help

**EDIT:** i dont think its my code but if it was here it is

some additional info about the code:

base.html

```
                <ul class="group" id="example-one">
                {% for i in mains %}
                <li class="{% block activetab %}{% endblock %}"><a href="{{ i.menulink }}">{{ i.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
```

whats included in certain views:

```
    {% block activetab %}
    {% ifequal request.get_full_path|cut:"/" i.menulink|cut:"/" %}current_page_item{% endifequal %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: seems like no element is found via selector $(".current_page_item a") so position() return `null` objeect and null object doesn't have `left` property (wild guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that menu buggs if there is no single li with current_page_item class, i hacked it by forcing:

```
{% ifequal ourprojects i.menulink|cut:"/" %}current_page_item{% endifequal %}
```

on single project view. 
ALthough it works now, it wont if someone changes the path to ourprojects in the admin panel.  I would still like to find a proper solution that would work even if someone changes the path... #or i could just disallow changing the path... but thats another sucky solution.

and so it stayed.